# MINUS on column and corresponding row

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I'm looking for a simple solution to getting the current row for a formula.

Column C is `Gross Pay`
Column D is `Net Pay`

I want Column E to be `Taxes Paid` by subtracting `D` from `C`.

All the answers I've seen have involved more complex uses so I'm a bit unclear on getting `current row`. Anything simple for this? I'm using Google Sheets, but any Excel guidance I can translate over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in E1.. put `=C1-D1` , then drag the formula until the last line.

Hope it helps. (:

---

For this part:

> getting the current row for a formula

you may use `=row()`